# Export Applescript to Application does change the permissions

Tags: passwords, applescript

I write a couple of applescripts as it is a natural language built in to MacOS without the need of using any additional editors or SW packages.

When I wrote a script I test it a couple of times and then export it to an application within the script editor. See this:
[Export Script to Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34Pxo.jpg)

When I execute the Script or the App it asks for entering the password (some of the commands require that). There is a difference though:
a) If I execute the script I can use TouchID:
[TouchID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLepF.jpg)
b) When I execute the app I need to enter the pwd:
[Enter Pwd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQeTH.jpg)

My question is why is the app not asking for TouchID but asks me to enter the password?

And, why is asking over and over again to allow access files in my folder?
[Allow Access to files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFM1w.jpg)

The "access to files/folder" question does not pop-up when running the script but only pops-up when executing the application.

Do you have any idea why the dialog changes from TouchID to Password entry and why the access dialog pops-up, and do you know what I can change to revert using TouchID and get rid of the access dialog permanently?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: The application needs to be code-signed or the script(s) in the bundle made read-only to avoid the repeated permission dialog.

Comment: Thanks Red! I do choose the code sign to "Run Locally" as you can see from the screenshot. But this seem not to help either.... not sure exactly how this all works but anyhow, thanks for your help!